# How to get the values from Access Database and set in Gridview in C# winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, gridview, devexpress

I have Gridview (gridview1), some TextEdits in the Form and add some Data's to few rows and i stored the gridview1 Data's and textedits to Access Database. In another form i Bind some column to gridview1 and TextEdits to new Gridview (gridview2). Now if i click edit button on any row in the gridview2, I want to get the Data's from Access Database and shown in 1st Form gridview1 and textedits fill automatically recording to Focused Row cell unique value.

Using this code i get value to TextEdits Fields

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Srihari/OrionSystem.accdb");

        OleDbCommand da = new OleDbCommand("select * from invoice_top where invoice_number=" + textEdit5.Text, con);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = da.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            textEdit12.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            textEdit13.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            textEdit4.Text = reader.GetString(3);
            dateEdit1.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
            textEdit1.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            textEdit2.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
            textEdit3.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
            checkEdit1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(4);
         }

        con.Close();
```

I also want to fill gridview Data's ? I tried this bus its not working

```
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns[2], reader1.GetString(2));
```

How to set Access Database values to grdiview ?? Please Help me ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read a tutorial on Data Binding.

The GridControl can be bound to a data source which implements IList<>, IBindingList<> or IQueryable<> simply by setting the GridControl.DataSource property. There is no need to loop through your recordset and set the value for each row/cell individually. Additionally, I would suggest you Data Bind your TextEdit controls (to the EditValue property, NOT the Text property) rather than manually setting them like you are doing above.

Answer (score 0):

This code is VB.NET but the ideea is the same in C#

```
 Dim SIRCON as string =  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Srihari/OrionSystem.accdb"

Using con As New OleDbConnection(SIRCON)
        con.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "select * from invoice_top where invoice_number=" + textEdit5.Text
        dim dt as new datatable
        dt.Load(New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conexiune).ExecuteReader())
        conexiune.Close()

        GridControl1.datasource = dt
        GridControl1.ForceInitialise

    End Using
```